# Setting nonce for each style and script in html on each get request (Express)

Tags: html, express, nonce

I am precompiling pug to html and using sendFile for the html files. I am unsure of the best way (let alone how) to set the nonce attributes on each style and script element in those html files, when they are requested.

I know a solution is to use render and just compile the pug on each request and set the nonces then, but I don't want to do that because it is not fast enough.

Would it be inefficient to read the html file and edit the nonces on each request?

Comment: What did you end up doing?

Comment: use stream to read/write the html, replace script, style, link rel="stylesheet" tags with the nonce inserted as an attribute.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/insert-nonces